# Query data from Azure Purview

Tags: azure, azure-purview

Moving from AWS Glue to Azure Purview and i am confused about something

Its is possible to query Azure purview data catalog/assets in the same way we can query from AWS Glue data catalog using AWS Athena?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, you cannot query data from Azure Purview.

The Purview search experience is powered by a managed search index. After a data source is registered with Purview, its metadata is indexed by the search service to allow easy discovery. The index provides search relevance capabilities and completes search requests by querying millions of metadata assets. Search helps you to discover, understand, and use the data to get the most value out of it.

The search experience in Purview is a three stage process:

- The search box shows the history containing recently used keywords
  and assets.
- When you begin typing the keystrokes, the search suggests
  the matching keywords and assets.
- The search result page is shown with assets matching the keyword entered.

For more details, refer to [Understand search features in Azure Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/purview/concept-search).

Comment: Good answer, many people confuse auzre purview data catalog with aws glue while in thoery Purview is a data governance tool